# How can I add parameters to a command I am defining in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code that I am using to assign a command:

```
private ICommand aButtonClickedCommand;

public ICommand AButtonClickedCommand => 
       aButtonClickedCommand ??
       (aButtonClickedCommand = new Command(ProcessButtonClickedCommand));

private void ProcessButtonClickedCommand()
{
   App.DB.IncrementPoints(Settings.cfs, phrasesFrame.phrase, 1, 2);
   Change.points = true;
   phrasesFrame.CancelTimer2();
 }
```

As I wanted to add some parameters I changed it to this:

```
public ICommand AButtonClickedCommand => 
       aButtonClickedCommand ?? 
       (aButtonClickedCommand = new Command(ButtonClickedCommand((int)Settings.aBtn, 1)));

private void ButtonClickedCommand(int pts, int col)
{
    App.DB.IncrementPoints(Settings.cfs, phrasesFrame.phrase, pts, col);
    Change.points = true;
    phrasesFrame.CancelTimer2();
}
```

However I am getting an error message saying:

> Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action' (CS1503)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a delegate for the command

```
public ICommand AButtonClickedCommand => 
    aButtonClickedCommand ?? 
    (aButtonClickedCommand = new Command(() => ButtonClickedCommand((int)Settings.aBtn, 1)));
```

Reference [Command Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Command?view=xamarin-forms)